# Erro ao alterar tabela SQLITE - no such column

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Incluí uma nova coluna numa tabela. Reinstalei a aplicação e na hora de salvar os dados há uma mensagem dizendo que não existe uma coluna pathImagem, no meu caso, na tabela clientes. Li algumas coisas a respeito e fui aconselhado a instalar novamente a aplicação e ainda sim não resolveu. Estou tentando fazer um `ALTER TABLE` mas talvez esteja fazendo errado. Peço ajuda. Obrigado.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import static br.gestaoBd.Login.db;
import static java.lang.Integer.TYPE;

public class BancoDados extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public BancoDados(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    EstruturaBanco.criarTabelas();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqld, int i, int i1) {

    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE [clientes] ADD COLUMN [pathImagem2] VARCHAR2(125) NOT NULL  ");
}
}
```

Estrutura do Banco

```
 import br.gestaoBd.Login;



public class EstruturaBanco {

public static void criarTabelas() {
    System.out.println("Criando as tabelas...");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [clientes] (");
    sb.append(" [id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,");
    sb.append(" [nome] VARCHAR2(70) NOT NULL,");
    sb.append(" [email] VARCHAR2(70) NOT NULL,");
    sb.append(" [telefone] VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,");
    sb.append(" [endereco] VARCHAR2(70) NOT NULL,");
    sb.append(" [rg] VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,");
    sb.append(" [cpf] VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,");
    sb.append(" [pathImagem2] VARCHAR2(125) NOT NULL);");
    Login.db.execSQL(sb.toString()); 

   ......................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao alterar a estrutura da BD é necessário informar a classe SQLiteOpenHelper(BancoDados) dessa alteração.

O mecanismo que ela utiliza é verificar o valor do parâmetro `version` passado no construtor com o número da versão da BD existente.
Caso ele seja superior executa o método `onUpgrade()` se for inferior executa o método `onDowngrade()`.

Assim, sempre que alterar a estrutura da BD, tem, ao instanciar a classe *BancoDados*, de incrementar em 1 o valor a passar ao parâmetro `version`.

O que normalmente se faz é declarar uma constante para o número da versão e quando se altera o código para gerar a BD altera-se também esse valor.

Sugiro que altere a classe *BancoDados* da seguinte forma:

```
public class BancoDados extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Constante para a versão
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //O nome da BD não muda, declare uma constante
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NomeBanco";

    //É possível agora simplificar o construtor
    public BancoDados(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    .....
    .....
}
```

Tem de reflectir a alteração do construtor em todos os locais onde cria uma instância de *BancoDados*.
Verificará que se tornou mais simples instanciar a classe *BancoDados* e que quando tiver que alterar a versão ela só é feita em um local.